# How to avoid bad_alloc?

Tags: c++

How can I avoid the `bad_alloc` error in the code below. It says C
called `abort` function:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
SIGABRT

#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n,p,count=0;
  double l,t;
  while(1)
  {
    cin>>n;
    if(n==0)
      break;
    else
    {
      int * arr;
      arr= new  int[n+1];
      for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        arr[i]=0;
      for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        if(arr[i]==0)
        {   p=i;
          count++;
          for (int j=2;p*j<=n;j++)
          {   
            arr[p*j]=1;
          }
        }

      }
      delete[] arr;
      l=(double(n))/(log(n));
      t=(((count-l))/count)*100;
      if(t<0)
        t=(-1)*t;
      printf("%.1lf\n",t);
    }
    count=0;
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: buy more ram? if you try to allocate more memory than what your system can provide the only way to avoid errors is to not allocate that much memory

Comment: On which input does it fail?

Comment: `l` is a poor name for a variable, since it looks so much like the number `1`.

Comment: Since you seem to assign only 0s or 1s to your array, you could choose a data type smaller than int, but with a bigger array size you will eventually have the same problem again.

Answer (score 1):

While available RAM will limit the amount of memory you can allocate, you can handle the exception itself through a `try {...} catch(std::bad_alloc& err) {...}` block. Once you catch the `std::bad_alloc` exception, attempt to free some memory (if you can) before you go back to allocating more memory.  Additionally, you may want to look into a memory pool of some type if you are going to make a bunch of small allocations due to the fact that allocating and releasing small blocks of memory will over time create memory fragmentation issues where there is enough memory to keep allocating blocks, but not enough *contiguous* memory to make a valid allocation.  By having your own pool, you can better handle fragmentation issues through optimizing allocations for small blocks, etc.